# jssor Slider Carousel: Is it possible to set 'circular: false'?

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I'm implementing jssor Slider Carousel into a website, and have everything working well.
My slider's based upon the 'carousel.source.html' example from the 'Jssor.Slider.FullPack'.

http://www.vsdesign.com.au/index.php/projects/branding/united_panel_works

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: 1,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlaySteps: 3,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, default value is 3

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideDuration: 300,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            $SlideWidth: 138,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 92,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 6,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $Cols: 6,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $Align: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, direction navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)



            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create direction navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $Steps: 3                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options);
    });
</script>
```

However I've noticed that it defaults to slide from the end slide to the first one, and vice-versa.
In other sliders and carousels I've dealt with, there's been a parameter called circular or similar to deal with this function.

Looking through the configuration options, I wasn't able to find any parameter for this.
I tried using the syntax provided and input the line below into the initialisation, but had no luck.

```
$Circular: false,
```

Is anyone aware of a way of removing circular scrolling for the jssor carousel slider, or if there's a parameter for that?

Answer (score 1):

Please set $Loop option to 0

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            ...
            $Loop: 0,
            ...

        };

        var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer! if you're using a thumbnail gallery you'll need to set `$Loop: false` in `$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions` as well.